# Is there a way to select nth-child globally?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an HTML structure looks like this, I want to select all odd `<span>`s globally ignoring their parent elements.

Is there a way to make `1`, `3`, `5`, `7`, `9` red? I tried `:nth-child(odd)` but I think it only counts locally.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: spans;
}

span {
  counter-increment: spans;
}

span::after {
  content: counter(spans);
}
    
span:nth-child(odd) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not how `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` selectors work:

- `:nth-child(expr)` only selects elements with an ordinal position within their containing parent element that satisfies `expr`, and not their ordinal position in the entire document, or any other arbitrary ancestor: only their ordinal position within immediate parent element matters.
- `:nth-of-type` only selects elements with an ordinal position *within their siblings* that satisfies `expr`, which also implies the selector is evaluated independently of "cousin" elements in the DOM tree.
- ...so what you're asking is not currently possible using only CSS selectors: there is no `:nth-overall` or `:nth-of-type-overall` pseudoclass selector.
- You can still implement this using a client-script to add a named classes to those elements manually when the document loads.

i.e. something like this:

```js
const allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for( let i = 1; i < allSpans.length; i += 2 ) {
    allSpans[i].classList.add( 'isGloballyOdd' );
}
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: spans;
}

span {
  counter-increment: spans;
}

span::after {
  content: counter(spans);
}
    
span.isGloballyOdd {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

...which looks like this:

[image]